# Converting double to string. Boost Libraries appear not to work, and sstream causes "SEG FAULT"

Tags: c++, boost, casting, double, lexical

I have a simple problem, and I think I'm just doing something stupid which is causing a SEGFAULT.

I simply want to convert a double variable to a string, and then 'strcat()' them both together and put the resultant concatenated string in a GTK Label. (It should be simple, surely?!)

Here is a section of my code:

```
double fps_target = 2.71828
std::string fps_target_string;
std::stringstream convert;
convert << fps_target;
fps_target_string = convert.str();
g_print("seg fault occurs below");
label_fps_target = gtk_label_new(strcat("FPS Target: ", 
    (const char*) fps_target_string.c_str()));
```

Why cannot it work?! :(

I tried using the Boost::Lexical_Cast thing, but that didn't work:

```
double fps_target = 3.14159;
const char* fps_target_string = (const char*) (boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(fps_target));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. If either method works that would be awesome, but I'm not really bothered about how to do it, so long as I can get a double to cat with a string!

Answer (score 8):

It shouldn't even compile. Make sure you have your compiler's warning and conformance levels set to high. That will save you much trouble in the long run.

Let us look at [`strcat`'s signature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat):

```
char *strcat( char *dest, const char *src );
```

So, it takes a `char*` as first parameter. But `"FPS Target: "` has type `char const[13]` which decays to `char const*`, which cannot be passed as a `char*`. `char*` allows modification, but `char const*` doesn't (string literals are not mutable!). This first parameter is `char*` because that's the buffer where the result will be put. You can't put it in that string literal because:

1. String literals are read-only;
2. That string literal is not large enough.

The second argument doesn't need a cast, as the return type of `c_str()` is already `char const*`.

The simplest way to concatenate strings is to use `std::string` and not bother with the C library string manipulation functions.

```
std::string result = "FPS Target: " + fps_target_string;
g_print("seg fault doesn't occur below");
label_fps_target = gtk_label_new(result.c_str());
```

Since the code is already using a `stringstream`, an even easier way would be to just insert both parts into the stream.

```
std::stringstream convert;
convert << "FPS Target: " << fps_target;
std::string result = convert.str();
g_print("seg fault doesn't occur below");
label_fps_target = gtk_label_new(result.c_str());
```

Comment: Aaach! Of course, thanks so much man. I knew I was doing something stupid!

Answer (score 1):

`strcat()` uses the first parameter as the output buffer. Of course, `strcat("FPS Target: "...)` will crash. Allocate a buffer and pass it as a first parameter.

`const char* fps_target_string = (const char*) boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(fps_target)` won't compile, because there's no conversion from std::string to `const char*`.